# Is there a name for “c'est” clauses?

Tags: grammaire, terminologie, syntaxe, subordonnées

In the sentence “Ce que je trouve remarquable, c'est que …”, the phrase “c'est” introduces a new clause. Other sentences in French also follow such a pattern. Is there a name for such clauses?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to analyse the construction in which is found the form "c'est que" and 2 corresponding descriptive terms for the clause:

- "proposition complétive en fonction d'apposition au pronom « ce »" (TLFi). There are alternative terms for "copmlétive": "conjonctive" and "nominalisée" ([free encyclopedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_(grammaire)#Les_propositions_compl%C3%A9tives_ou_nominalis%C3%A9es_ou_conjonctives)).
- "proposition conjonctive à fonction de suite d'un introducteur"; another term for "introducteur" is  "présentatif" (LBU § 1224 f). Here the "introducteur" is "c'est".

> ([TLFi)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) [Introd. une complét. en fonction d'appos.]
>   b) [Apposée au pron. ce]
>   ) C'est que (littéral. « ceci est, à savoir que... »). Introduit une explication de ce qui précède ou bien une objection, une rectification à ce qui vient d'être dit.
>
> (LBU § 1126 f)  f) Suite des introducteurs « voici », « voilà », « c'est »

Answer (score -3):

*"C'est"* is the contraction of *"Cela est"*, so it's a pronoun and a verb, which make *"C'est"* a verbal group.